# Android-MarqueeRepeatlimit="marquee_forever" tag in XML

Tags: android

i want to set MarqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" at run-time is there any possible way to do that, if anyone known about this help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMarqueeRepeatLimit%28int%29) should get you going

```
mTextView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
```